# Rails AJAX Get url not found

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

When doubleClick an element, I'm trying to get a url, then pull the replace the html of `#propertiesBox` with the contents of that url.

```
$('.elemContainer').dblclick(function() {

    $.get("/ui/propertiesBox", function(data) {
        $("#propertiesBox").html(data);
        alert("Load was performed.");
    });

});
```

The url I want to get is `views/ui/_propertiesBox.html.erb`

Comment: You have the controller action/route for /ui/propertiesBox url?

Comment: Could you please share your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Nothing in my routes.rb file about ui or propertiesBox. Should I add something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a route for that url:

```
#routes
get 'ui/propertiesBox' => 'some_controller#properties_box'
```

And appropriate action in controller:

```
#controller 
def properties_box
  render :partial => 'propertiesBox'
end
```

To make it happen.